# Convert 2 columns to 4 columns on angular material

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

I am using angular material. That uses flex.
I need to have 2 columns on mobile and 4 columns on desktop.

Because some cards are expandable, that means that will have different height, the order doesn't matter to much.

I tried different configurations but without success. Is it possible to do this with flexbox?

[image: 2 cols on mobile, 4 cols on desktop]

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Post some example code, meanwhile take a look at the gridList, maybe this is what you are looking for.
[link]https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList

Answer (score 1):

you can use fxFlex.lg="25" fxFlex.xs="50" for responsive as per screen size.
for more information use [flex layout doc](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/responsive)